# c++ winapi CreateProcess Suspended recognized as malicious

Tags: c++, winapi, process, createprocess

```
CreateProcessA(szFilePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI)
```

Just like in the title, windows recognize this line as malicious. I checked it by deleting lines in my project. This line causes my project being recognized as "Worm:Win32/Rebhip.A" type of virus. I have to create suspended process, is there any alternative to avoid this kind of warnings?

Comment: Get a better virus checker.

Comment: Seriously, there is no other library i can use to create process in windows?

Comment: It sounds to me as if there's more to the story than this. I've created suspended processes many times, without any anti-virus (or similar) program having any problem at all.

Comment: Checked creation of normal process, that's not that line.

Comment: You could try skipping kernel32 and call `NtCreateProcess()` directly, but the native API is not for the faint of heart.  In the meantime I'd suggest you file a ticket with your antivirus vendor about this issue.

Comment: Anti-virus heuristics use combinations of factors, and like any heuristic, there are always borderline cases.  The fact that adding this single line happens to push your application from just-barely-OK to just-barely-malicious doesn't really mean that any application with that line will be considered malicious.  You might just have to whitelist it for now, hopefully once the project is complete it will no longer be borderline.  Adding a digital signature may help.  (Creating the child process in a more complicated way is likely to make your application look more suspicious rather than less.)

Comment: On the other hand, if it is a signature-based detection, that's just bad luck, and trivial changes may well fix the problem.  Try passing a valid command line, for example, rather than NULL.

Comment: What about api call encryption? Would solve the problem?

Comment: @MrEricSir NtCreateProcess is absolutely not the way to go, you will end up with CSRSS and SxS problems...

Comment: @Anders Oh believe me, you're lucky if that's the *least* of your problems when you use the native API in application code!

Comment: Your observation is wrong: It is definitely not Windows, that gets upset. It's rather 3rd party software, like a virus scanner, which is basically a malware tool that promises to protect you from other malware.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a suspend process is sometimes used for evil purposes by viruses so they can change `CONTEXT->EIP` or inject a thread in a Microsoft/Mozilla .exe and then bypass the firewall etc. but those tricks are old and probably don't work anymore?

There are also absolutely legitimate reasons for starting a suspended process, attaching it to a Job object is one example.

I would recommend that you whitelist your application while developing it and hopefully when it is complete it no longer triggers the Anti-Virus. This really depends on whether it is triggered by a signature or run-time heuristics. If it still triggers on your finished application you need to [submit a false-positive report](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-report-malware-or-false-positives-multiple-antivirus-vendors.htm) to the vendor and perhaps name and shame them...